# Rails - button_tag using hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I tried to simplify my code from this:

```
button_tag default_button[:name] ? default_button[:name] : t(button.to_s) , type: default_button[:type] ? default_button[:type] : 'submit', class: default_button[:class] ? default_button[:class] : "btn_#{button.to_s}"
```

To this:
`button_tag(default_button)`

But it doesn't work, I get the whole hash as text in the button. How can I make it smart to use the hash key/values?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, the first parameter is a bit special.

`concat button_tag(default_button[:name], default_button)`